# The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FF8A37BA203 (00007FF8A3710000) with exit code 80131506

Tags: .net, iis

Hi My webservices just started crashing unexpectedly with the below error

Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FF8A37BA203 (00007FF8A3710000) with exit code 80131506.

Comment: Critical crash cases like that can only be analyzed/resolved by Microsoft support if you open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com . You might also try to upgrade to latest .NET Framework (such as 4.8) to see if it happens to be resolved there.